# How to withdraw 20 dollars continually from a file

Tags: linux, shell-script

How can I write a script that will continuously withdraw 20 of dollars from an account until the balance is depleted (or the remainder is less than 20 dollars). Once completed, I have to echo back to the user how many 20 dollar bills they have received. I have to use arguments to specify the account file.

This is what i have so far in my script

```
file1=$(cat $1)
while (( file1  >= 20 ))
do
echo $(($file1 - 20)) > $1
done
```

If someone can help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: this looks like homework, so here's a hint: increment a counter inside the loop, then print it after the loop.

Comment: Also make sure to name your variables according to what they contain, for instance *balance* instead of *file1*.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is almost complete.

The only thing you have to do is maintain a counter to count the withdrawals.

As people suggested in the comments you should give the variables easy-to-understand names.

```
balance=$(cat "$1")
count=0

while (( balance  >= 20 ))
do

    (( ccount++ ))
    echo $(( balance -= 20)) > "$1"
    balance=$(cat "$1")

done
printf '%d withdrawals\n' $count
```

If you don't want to update the file in every step, it's simpler;

```
balance=$(cat "$1")
count=0

while (( balance  >= 20 ))
do

    (( ccount++ ))
    (( balance -= 20))

done
printf '%d\n' $balance > "$1"
printf '%d withdrawals\n' $count
```

Comment: hey nizam my while loop isnt working. giving me these errors "./withdraw: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/withdraw: line 3: `while (( $balance  -ge 20 ))"

Comment: You can't use `-ge` operator within `((...))` compound command. If you want to use `-ge` form of comparison you must use one of `[[...]]`, `[...]` or `test`

Answer (score 0):

Or ..... if you want to keep a record of your transactions just update the account and count the number of lines - 1 (for the original balance)

```
balance=$(cat account)
while (( balance >= 20 )); do 
    (( balance -= 20 ))
    echo $balance >> account;
done
echo "$(( $(cat account | wc -l)-1 )) transactions were made and your balance is \$$(tail -n 1 account)"
```

Comment: "./withdraw: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/withdraw: line 4: `    (( balance -= 20 ))"                                                                                still giving me issues with these errors.

Comment: Odd, Works fine for me. Try changing the line to `balance=$(( balance - 20 )), Does it work if you just `echo 1951 > account` and then just copy paste the code into the terminal?